Connection refused when using Sequelize with MySQL running on Docker
I am building a dockerized API with MYSQL. I have already set up a network between the two services but Sequelize is returning a connection refused error.
Here is my Dockerfile for the API
FROM node:20

COPY . /app/


WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "./dist/index.js"]

The docker-compose.yml
services:
  node_app:
    container_name: node_app
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9000:3000"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DB=shopper-test-db
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_HOST=node_db
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - node_db

  node_db:
    container_name: node_db
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=shopper-test-db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

The sequelize connection
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.MYSQL_DB,
  "root",
  process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    dialect: "mysql",
  }
);

export default sequelize;


I have looked up the issue and for others it was a matter of changing the host  propriety form 'localhost' to the mysql container, I have already checked and I am not making that mistake, so I don't know what is wrong

You probably need to wait for the MySQL service to be ready. This is a very common problem
